# Read the value from a file with Python

Tags: python, sed, subprocess

My file contents:

```
NAME="A"
VERSION="20190515231057-816a"
VERSION_ID="2.0"
BUILD_ID="16a438d965923ab62804cea4ba00"
BUILDER_NAME="v1.0"
BUILDER_VERSION="v1.0"
```

I need to read any data value, for example `BUILDER_VERSION` is value (v1.0). I tried following code however it gives error due to special characters. How can I fix the problem or please suggest different commands?

```
build_value = subprocess.check_output("sed -ne 's/BUILDER_VERSION=\([^]*\).*/\1/p' < /etc/os-release", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you could avoid using subprocess for such simple case. You can read file directly with open() or accept "standard input" from `sys.stdin` (you would need to import sys before that).

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('BUILDER_VERSION='):
          value = line.split('=', 1)
          print(value[1] if value or 'No version')
          break
 else:
      print('version is not found')
```

you would use it similar to sed: `cat /etc/os-release|python this_script.py`

if want to extract number, you could use same regex:

```
import re
version_extractor = re.compile(r'BUILDER_VERSION=([^^]*)')

with open('/etc/os-release', 'r') as file:
   for line in file:
       match = version_extractor.match(line)
       if match:
           print(match.groups()[0])
```

Comment: @lokesh-chandak Hi, Thanks you for fixing formatting. But I reverted your 1 change to the "else" clause. This way code will print "version is not found" only once at the end of stream if no match were found.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
with open(FILE_NAME, 'r') as file:
    parsed = file.read().split('\n')
    for item in parsed:
        if VAR_NAME in item:
            print(item)
```

That would print the entire line of the file containing the variable name. You could also save the line as a string literal and break it down further with slicing, splitting, regex, etc.

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do that, though, so I would check out some Python documentation on reading files!

Answer (score 0):

Replace sed command with following:

```
sed -n 's/^BUILDER_VERSION*= *//p' < /etc/os-release
```

you can replace BUILDER_VERSION with required pattern

Answer (score 0):

I Changed `sed -n 's/^BUILDER_VERSION*= *//p' < /etc/os-release` command. Now fine working. Also I added .replace('"', '') to the end of the subprocess command for v1.0.
Thank you everyone.